# Can we use a real device to see swift UI Previews?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios13

I was wondering if there is a way where we can connect the real device to xcode and see swift UI live previews on device.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, we can... connect device and tap bottom preview button, or select menu item by right click

[image: demo]

Comment: I am not able to see the context menu.

Comment: This button enables preview on device but doesn't disable preview in xcode. How to disable preview in xcode too?

Answer (score 1):

(2022 answer)

1. First build and run your app on your device.
2. After this the `Preview on Device` button will light up. Click on it.
3. Your device will now show the `Xcode Previews` app on your device and will run the preview.

[image]